# How to I access SharePoint schema from outside the server?

Tags: list

I am a VBA developer with limited experience with .NET.  Ideally I'd like to manipulate objects (specifically change a linked list) on a SharePoint site.  However, I am not on the SharePoint box.  I am working remotely.  Can I manipulate a SharePoint site using VS.NET and, if so, what object libraries do I need to reference?"

Comment: By `VS.NET` do you mean Visual Studio? Also do you want to access SharePoint Lists using VBA or ok with C# or VB.NET ?

Comment: I would prefer to access via VBA but Visual Studio.NET (VB or C#) would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to access `SharePoint` from a remote machine on which SharePoint is not installed, then we should use `Client Object Model`.

**Client Object Model**: It is a feature of SharePoint. It provides features to program against a SharePoint site using `.NET Managed Code` or `JavaScript`. The `Client Object Model` provides almost all the programming features of the Server Object Model such as accessing `Custom Lists/Libraries`, `Add/Edit/Delete` operation on lists etc., plus advantages in deployment.

SharePoint exposes three Object models which are as follows:

- Managed
- Silverlight
- JavaScript (ECMAScript)

Read more on [WORKING WITH CLIENT OBJECT MODEL IN MICROSOFT SHAREPOINT](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/working-client-object-model-microsoft-sharepoint)

Before we start developing, we must ensure that we have required client namespaces installed.

For `SharePoint 2010` you can download from [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=21786)

For `SharePoint 2013` you can download from [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

**Sample c# code using client object model** : For more details refer [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)

*Retrieve the properties of a website* :

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// The SharePoint web at the URL.
Web web = context.Web; 

// We want to retrieve the web's properties.
context.Load(web); 

// Execute the query to the server.
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

// Now, the web's properties are available and we could display 
// web properties, such as title. 
label1.Text = web.Title;
```

*Retrieve all SharePoint lists in a web* :

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// The SharePoint web at the URL.
Web web = context.Web; 

// Retrieve all lists from the server. 
context.Load(web.Lists, 
            lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, // For each list, retrieve Title and Id. 
                                    list => list.Id)); 

// Execute query. 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

// Enumerate the web.Lists. 
foreach (List list in web.Lists) 
{ 
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + list.Title; 
}
```

*Retrieve items from a SharePoint list* :

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
// so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100); 
ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query); 

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
context.Load(items); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
foreach (ListItem listItem in items) 
{ 
    // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + listItem["Title"]; 
}
```

*Create a new list item* :

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Body"] = "Hello World!"; 
newItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Asad:  thank you _very much_ for this posting.  My clients needs have changed and we have decided to go with SQL Server instead.  However, I intend to test your code and learn more as soon as I can.  In the meantime I am marking this as answered.

Comment: @TimothyJeffryes : Not a problem. Always happy to help. SharePoint is an awesome platform. You will love to learn and explore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access lists (read/update/add/delete) by using List Web service. Add http://yoursharepointsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx as a web reference in your VS.Net Project. You also need the permissions on the SharePoint Server to access these lists.

Lets assume that your web refernce name is listService, you can use

```
Dim ndLists As XmlNode = listService.GetList("List_Name")
```

to get a list. 
Go to this link to get all list methods with examples
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Lists.Lists_methods(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I am very much looking forward to checking out all this stuff.  Very exciting!  I'm so grateful!  I just need to find some time to try it all out.